# PHP file upload check - it is possible before sending the input via POST?

Tags: php, file, upload

I have a very basic code to upload form:

```
echo "<form action='upload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
echo "Select upload:   ";
echo "<input type='file' name='fileToUpload' id='fileToUpload'>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Upload file' name='submit'>";
echo "</form>";
```

Ok, now I want to check the input if the user has selected a file or not, but before sending the input filename via POST to another PHP file (upload.php)

I know that checking if no file has been selected can be done something like this:

```
if(!isset($_FILES['fileToUpload']) || $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
    echo "Error no file selected"; 
} else {
    echo "ok";
}
```

I know that somehow I need the check the input here in this file:

```
echo '<form action="'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).'" method="post">';
```

But how can mix these together ? I want to pass the filename to another php file, when a file is selected.

Thank you.

Comment: you can use JS to check that file has been selected or not before submitting the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check this with javascript you can use following

```
var filename = document.getElementById("DealImage").value;

if (filename != ''){
   alert('files selected');
}else{
   alert('empty files input');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to check file is selected or not on form submit.

```
if ( $('#fileToUpload').val() == '' || $('#fileToUpload').val() == null) {
    alert("Please select file");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help user27715!